# html page with auto fresh not displaying iframe when html page inside is being overwritten

Tags: html, batch-file, iframe, command-line, page-refresh

I have a batch file that adds finished jobs to a basic text file to create a logs .txt files.  I then have a process setup to add html code for tables, heading, banner, etc to the logs and save a copy as an Queue.html.  I then have an index.html that has an iframe of that Queue.html page.  The index has a meta http-equiv="refresh" for every 15 seconds.  The problem I'm running into is because the scheduled batch file is constantly overriding the Queue.html, the index.html will try to refresh while the page is being overwritten and will display a page not found error (HTTP 403).  Because I have this iframed and auto refreshing the error will go away after 15 seconds.  However, it doesn't make for a very clean page at times since I leave the page open to monitor the queue.  My knowledge of CSS and databases is very limited so I'm just curious if there are any simple recommendations on getting this page to refresh a little cleaner.

Thanks,

Comment: The question is very unclear and uses inaccurate language, please consider asking someone to help you phrase your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: I have now updated the wording on this question.  Because I'm new to the site I can not include code or screenshot attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how the batch file replaces the `Queue.html` file.

Instead of deleting it and creating a new one, first create the new file under a different file (say `Queue-next.html`), then rename the new file to the old name, replacing it. This will ensure that the web server never sees the file as being missing.

I'm not familiar with Windows commands so I can't advise you on the exact commands to use, but this is a standard technique for this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Does anyone know the override command for renaming a file to an existing one?  I'm getting a syntax error when I try that?

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting some more, I found a move override (move /y) command instead of a rename command on the same directory on the web server will rename/override the file without displaying an error on the index iframes.  Thanks for the ideas.